# Oracle Login issues

Tags: database, oracle, authentication

I have just created a new user on an newly created Oracle  12C database and cannot use it to login from either SQL*Plus or SQL Developer. What am I doing wrong? I can connect as SYSTEM but not as NEWGUY.

```
-- logged in as SYSTEM....

alter session set CONTAINER=PDBNEW

create user NEWGUY identified by FRED
grant connect to NEWGUY
```

I can connect as system but trying to connect changing only the username and password results in failure. (ORA-91917: invalid username/password; login denied.

I can see NEWGUY in the DBA_USERS table.

I'll amend this if you need more information....

Comment: You should probably be [granting `session` rather than `connect`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/users.htm#BABGCJGD), though `connect` should still work as far as I'm aware. What is your connect command - do you have the password case correct?

Comment: Are you aware that passwords are case-sensitive by default? If you supply `fred` (instead of `FRED`) as the password during login, you'd get exactly that message.

Comment: Are you attempting to [connect to the right container](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17636/cdb_admin.htm#BAJFCAEG)? I think you should be doing `connect newguy/FRED@pdbnew` but I'm not sure. (I haven't started working with 12c yet but I think you might not be doing that; you know the `alter session` you did earlier doesn't affect what the `connect` is accessing?).

Comment: Thanks for the things you've raised so far. I haven't used Oracle for some time. I deliberately set the username and password to upper case only to ensure there were no case sensitivity issues. Containers are new to me...

Comment: I think you should grant create session GRANT CREATE SESSION TO NEWGUY;

Comment: Using an all-uppercase password doesn't disable the case sensitivity of the password check. If you set your password to FRED, you'll have to use FRED, not fred or Fred or ... (this is quite different from the rules for *object names*, where an all-uppercase name isn't sensitive even if quoted)

Comment: You mentioned you hadn't used Oracle for a while; [case-sensitive passwords were introduced in 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authentication.htm#CHDBBGFG). Don't want to belabour the point, but that might be confusing if you weren't expecting it.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I deliberately set the password on this to uppercase 'FRED'. It looks like the problem is that I didn't know that you have to open a PDB as read/write or read/only, and that Oracle just has it mounted initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember everyone that if you create a PDB you have to open it and set it to read/write in order for it to be open for business.

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE myPDBDatabase OPEN READ WRITE;
```